# GridView CommandField issue

Tags: column, gridview

I have a small problem with a GridView in my web part. I bind a DataTable to the SourceData of my GridView and check if the current user is an administrator. If he is, I will add additional CommandField columns.
Here a part of my code:

```
protected void SumbitSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
...
GridViewResult.DataSource = null;
GridViewResult.BinData();
...
GridViewResult.DataSource = result;
GridViewResult.DataBind();
GridViewResult.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridViewResult.Rows)
{
    gvr.Cells[0].Visible = false;
}
GridViewResult.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Width = Unit.Pixel(175);
GridViewResult.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Width = Unit.Pixel(175);
GridViewResult.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Text = "Von: " + languageFrom;
GridViewResult.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Text = "Nach: " + languageTo;
//if() Check admin
//{
    CommandField deleteButton = new CommandField();
    deleteButton.ShowDeleteButton = true;
    GridViewResult.Columns.Add(deleteButton);
//}
...
}
```

If I deploy my web part, and click on my button, nothing happens. If I click a second time, suddenly the Ident column appears. If I click a third time, the delete Button appear. A fourth time a second delete Button appear and so on.
I think the problem occur, because the new delete button column will add at the first column in the table. How could I fix this?

Btw is it possible to set a css style for the button? If I use `deleteButton. ControlStyle.CssClass =""`; the css class is valid for the complete table.

**Last Change:**

Okay, now I did it witch `CreateChildControls()`. But it doesn’t work right. The Button will only displayed at the last row of the Table and the event handler would not be fired.

My `CreateChildControls()` looks like:

```
...
protected Button deleteButton;
...

if((Page.IsPostBack) && ( // Check if admin == true )
{
    //Controls.Clear();
    deleteButton = new Button();
    deleteButton.Text = "Löschen";
    deleteButton.Click += new EventHandler(clickd);
    base.CreateChildControls();
}
```

Later i add a new cell to every row of the gridview:

```
TableCell test = new TableCell();
int i = 0;
while (i < GridViewResult.Rows.Count)
{                           
    deleteButton.ID = "delete_" + GridViewResult.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
    test.Controls.Add(deleteButton);
    GridViewResult.Rows[i].Cells.Add(test);
    i++;
}
```

I would like to have, a delete button for every row in my table. At the runtime, I dont know how many rows the result have. Is it generally possible to add a control in a function outside of `CreateChildControls()` if the control is created in the `CreateChildControls`?
What works wrong?

Greetz, Taz

Comment: Well I'd say the first problem is that you are adding the button in a postback function. Do you have a CreateChildControls function?

Comment: No i haven't. Do you mean to overwrite the CreateChildControls and add here the controls?

Comment: This turned out to be very interesting! I added an example to my answer. Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating the CommandField button in a postback event: `SumbitSearch_Click`. Take a look at [Wictor's wonderful graphic](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/SharePoint-Web-Part-Event-Flow-in-detail.aspx).

Instead, you should be overriding the `CreateChildControls` function and creating most of your controls there. You'll notice, however, that on a postback the `CreateChildControls` will be called before your `SumbitSearch_Click` function (which makes sense if you think about it.. the button must exist before the button click event can fire).

You could use the `Page.IsPostback` within `CreateChildControls` to have some separate logic or use `OnPreRender` to make the decision since it will run after your events.

---

Here is an example which uses the session as a DataSource.

[image: SPGridView with query and delete]

The code:

```
class SimpleGridView : CompositeControl
{
    private const string SESSION_ID = "SalesData";
    private ObjectDataSource _gridDS;
    private TextBox _txtQuery;
    private SPGridView _grid;

    public DataView SelectData(string query)
    {
        DataTable dataSource = null;

        // using session to simulate a "delete", otherwise it would do nothing each time :)
        if (null == this.Page.Session[SESSION_ID])
        {
            dataSource = new DataTable();

            // setup columns
            dataSource.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
            dataSource.Columns.Add("Name");
            dataSource.Columns.Add("Region");
            dataSource.Columns.Add("Total Sales", Type.GetType("System.Double"));
            dataSource.Columns.Add("Created", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));

            // add some bogus data
            dataSource.Rows.Add(1, "J. Smith", "Europe", 10000, new DateTime(2010, 10, 7, 8, 0, 0));
            dataSource.Rows.Add(2, "J. Smith", "North America", 15000, new DateTime(2010, 10, 8, 9, 00, 0));
            dataSource.Rows.Add(3, "J. Smith", "Asia", 5000, new DateTime(2010, 10, 7, 10, 0, 0));
            dataSource.Rows.Add(4, "S. Jones", "Europe", 7000, new DateTime(2010, 10, 9, 11, 0, 0));
            dataSource.Rows.Add(5, "S. Jones", "North America", 30000, new DateTime(2010, 10, 7, 9, 00, 0));
            dataSource.Rows.Add(6, "S. Jones", "Asia", 8700, new DateTime(2010, 10, 9, 8, 0, 0));
            dataSource.Rows.Add(7, "W. Nguyen", "Europe", 3000, new DateTime(2010, 10, 8, 8, 0, 0));
            dataSource.Rows.Add(8, "W. Nguyen", "North America", 50000, new DateTime(2010, 10, 7, 12, 30, 0));
            dataSource.Rows.Add(9, "W. Nguyen", "Asia", 25000, new DateTime(2010, 10, 7, 8, 0, 0));
            dataSource.Rows.Add(10, "C. O'Reilly", "Europe", 200, new DateTime(2008, 1, 16, 15, 0, 0));
            dataSource.Rows.Add(11, "C. O'Reilly", "North America", 5000, new DateTime(2009, 11, 1, 16, 0, 0));
            dataSource.Rows.Add(12, "C. O'Reilly", "Asia", 8000, new DateTime(2010, 10, 9, 19, 0, 0));
            this.Page.Session[SESSION_ID] = dataSource;
        }
        else
        {
            dataSource = (DataTable)this.Page.Session[SESSION_ID];
        }

        DataView view = new DataView(dataSource);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {
            query = query.Replace("'", "''");
            view.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", query);
        }

        return view;
    }

    public void DeleteItem(int row_id)
    {
        // do some sort of delete action against our datasource
        // in this simple case, we're just deleting rows from the session
        DataTable dataSource = (DataTable)this.Page.Session[SESSION_ID];
        DataRow[] rows = dataSource.Select(string.Format("ID = {0}", row_id));
        if (null != rows && rows.Length == 1)
        {
            rows[0].Delete();
        }
    }

    private void AddBoundField(string name)
    {
        BoundField column = new BoundField();
        column.DataField = name; // must match the column name in the datasource
        column.SortExpression = name;
        column.HeaderText = name;
        _grid.Columns.Add(column);
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        _txtQuery = new TextBox();
        _txtQuery.ID = "txtQuery";
        this.Controls.Add(_txtQuery);

        // really all this is good for is causing the page to post back
        Button btnSubmit = new Button();
        btnSubmit.ID = "btnSubmit";
        btnSubmit.Text = "Submit";
        btnSubmit.Click += new EventHandler(btnSubmit_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(btnSubmit);

        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            // don't display the grid until they click submit at least once
            CreateGridView();
        }
    }

    void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // clear so that they can query multiple times
        _gridDS.SelectParameters.Clear();

        // they clicked the button so set our query
        _gridDS.SelectParameters.Add("query", _txtQuery.Text);
    }

    private void CreateGridView()
    {
        const string GRIDID = "grid";
        const string DATASOURCEID = "gridDS";

        // initialize the ODS
        _gridDS = new ObjectDataSource();
        _gridDS.ID = DATASOURCEID;
        // calling our SelectData function in this CompositeControl
        _gridDS.SelectMethod = "SelectData";
        // calls our Delete Item method when they click our CommandField delete button
        _gridDS.DeleteMethod = "DeleteItem";
        // so our grid datasource knows which object to ask for data
        _gridDS.TypeName = this.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
        _gridDS.ObjectCreating += new ObjectDataSourceObjectEventHandler(gridDS_ObjectCreating);
        // we need this event in order to add parameters that will be used for our delete method
        // otherwise it can't find it
        _gridDS.Deleting += new ObjectDataSourceMethodEventHandler(_gridDS_Deleting);

        this.Controls.Add(_gridDS);

        // Initialize the grid and link it to the ObjectDataSource
        _grid = new SPGridView();
        _grid.ID = GRIDID;
        _grid.DataSourceID = _gridDS.ID;
        _grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        // Paging
        _grid.AllowPaging = true;
        _grid.PageSize = 10;

        // Sorting
        _grid.AllowSorting = true;

        this.Controls.Add(_grid);

        // add our columns to the grid
        AddBoundField("ID");
        AddBoundField("Name");
        AddBoundField("Region");
        AddBoundField("Total Sales");
        AddBoundField("Created");

        // our column that shows the delete button a user can click
        CommandField cfDelete = new CommandField();
        cfDelete.ShowDeleteButton = true;
        cfDelete.ButtonType = ButtonType.Button;
        cfDelete.DeleteText = "Delete";
        _grid.Columns.Add(cfDelete);

        // needed to allow deleting rows using ID
        // if you don't have this, nothing is sent to your ObjectDataSource "Deleting" event
        string[] dataKeyNames = { "ID" };
        _grid.DataKeyNames = dataKeyNames;

        // setting PagerTemplate to null here will display page numbers for paging
        _grid.PagerTemplate = null;
    }

    void _gridDS_Deleting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
    {
        // This function isn't needed if your ObjectDataSource.DeleteMethod parameters
        // exactly match the column names in your datasource. I found this confusing
        // so I do a little conversion

        // it will be null if the column is not present in the grid's DataKeyNames
        if (null != e.InputParameters["ID"])
        {
            int id = (int)e.InputParameters["ID"];

            // clear the collection of parameters or it will try to find
            // a delete function that has every single parameter
            e.InputParameters.Clear();
            // notice that this parameter name matches the parameter in our delete method
            // which was set on the grid's objectdatasource
            e.InputParameters.Add("row_id", id);
        }
    }

    private void gridDS_ObjectCreating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        // our ObjectDataSource uses this CompositeControl to select data
        e.ObjectInstance = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Taz I think you still want to use your `CommandField deleteButton`. That will add a delete button to each row for you. I think I can create an example for you since I have some code already.

Comment: That's great! Thank you. You earned a new achievement: New blog reader. :) Greetz.